# Non-Deprecated Google Image API

Tags: javascript, google-image-search

I am writing an AngularJS app that would retrieve the first image from a Google Image search and display it to the user. I looked at the Google Image API but has been deprecated. What API should I be using?

I tried using the Google Custom Search API but it seems to be filtering my requests. For example, if I am to perform a Google Image Search on 'Miami', I would see photos of the Miami skyline. Performing the same query search with the Google Custom Search yielded results of lightbulbs.

Comment: CSE is a little weirder now.  Make sure when you set up your custom search engine you pick Sites to Search > 'Search the entire web...'.  I used mine to search for Miami and got e.g. this little dandy: https://media.timeout.com/images/103859094/image.jpg

Comment: Will this information be useful for you, although that is created by golang? https://github.com/tanaikech/goris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way now to get Google Search results is to scrape from the web pages although it's forbidden by Google's Terms of Use (so you can be banned and there are captchas when you send too many requests).

You'll have to use a server to scrape data because of CORS.

Comment: I'm guessing you mean 'scrape', not 'scrap'. Darn it - that was the answer I was not hoping for.